# makefile and multiple executions

Tags: c, makefile

I have a big project in C which is built using a make file and accepts multiple command line arguments like make DSP=1 DEBUG=1 LX=1  etc etc

To complete my experiment I need to build this program by passing different arguments. Can I create a file in which I can write all these multiple execution statements?

I know there must be some way to do this but I'm new to linux so cnt make out. Executing each make individually would be too hectic.

Answer (score 1):

Just write (or generate automatically) a text file with all your commands one per line. Then to run all the commands in sequence just type

```
bash <filename>
```

the normal unix way would be adding a line with `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning and then doing a `chmod +x` to make the file executable, but just calling bash is easier and allows using the same file also on windows (just name the file "something.bat").

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with a shell script, do it in make. This way you get the advantages of make: detection on broken compiles; parallel operation; all the stuff in one place, etc.

```
.PHONY: all
all:
    ${MAKE} bigcompile DSP=1 DEBUG=1 LX=1
    ${MAKE} bigcompile DSP=0 DEBUG=1 LX=1
    ${MAKE} bigcompile DSP=1 DEBUG=0 LX=1
    ${MAKE} bigcompile DSP=0 DEBUG=0 LX=1
    ∶

bigcompile:
    ∶
```

If you have written your makefile properly, then it should be possible to run several `bigcompile`s all *at the same time*. In this case you need to tell make that it can run more than one *bigcompile* at once:

```
.PHONY: all
all: compile1 compile2 compile3 compile4 ; @echo $@ success

.PHONY: compile1 compile2 compile3 compile4
compile1: ; ${MAKE} bigcompile DSP=1 DEBUG=1 LX=1
compile2: ; ${MAKE} bigcompile DSP=0 DEBUG=1 LX=1
compile3: ; ${MAKE} bigcompile DSP=1 DEBUG=0 LX=1
compile4: ; ${MAKE} bigcompile DSP=0 DEBUG=0 LX=1
∶
```

(There is clear opportunity to shrink this boilerplate text.)

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer was given by [@6502](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320726/6502).

Another trick you need to know is how to make sure that everything is rebuilt on the rerun.  With GNU Make, you can use the `-B` (or `--always-make`) option.  If you are not using GNU Make, you can run your cleanup (`make clean`) to remove the built files.  If you don't yet have a `clean` target, you will need to add one.